# how many google scrip files a google sheet can have

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

Do you know how many google scrip files a google sheet can have? I created 9 google scrip files for a google sheet (each file does different work).  But, when I run one of them (I opened this file at the Script Editor's interface ), but it run another script file that I did not open. So, how can I run the one I want to run? Or google sheet has a quota on the number of scrip files?

Thanks

Comment: Have you to tried to close all other applications and tabs? Have you took a look to the task manager of your browser and computer? What OS and web browser are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure what the upper number is or even if there is one. But I keep a lot of script files from past answers on this site in one project so I'd guess that the max if there is one is greater that 150 script files per google apps script project and I don't know how many projects per spreadsheet but again I'd guess that it's pretty high.  I would guess that you problem probably has more to do with function names.  That is to say that all function names have to be unique in all of the scripts.  So if you use on_open() as a function then you can only use that once in all of the script files.

Comment: Thank you very much Cooper and Ruben, After I changed the function names to different ones. They run well before I published them. However, when I published them, It always published the one I do not want to publish. Do you know what is happening. thanks. I am using Firefox, Windows 7 professional.

Comment: I published them using  'Deploy as web app'.

Comment: As Cooper said, each function name has to be unique. In addition `onEdit` `onChange` `doGet` are function names that will trigger based on an event. For example if you call a function `onEdit` it will always run on any manual edit to the spreadsheet. In addition to @Cooper I have not seen a way to create more than 1 project for a single file. You would need standalone projects for that. Deploying as web app is for a specific version. So check at the top of the pop up window when deploying. If you made changes, it should say "New", otherwise you will be deploying an older version.

Comment: @ICanPassDrivingSchoolLLC Please [edit] your question to update / include details on it because comments are intended to be to ask clarifications and to be temporary. Please clarify if by "script file" you actually mean an script file (a file inside a project) or if you mean an project so your spreadsheet has several projects.

Comment: @Vytautas: To add a new project on the script editor click  File > New...> Project

Comment: Thank you so much, Ruben,  Vytautas,Cooper, Yes, Ruben, I mean script files. I created a new project as Ruben instructed. and copied code from a previous project code file that runs well. I just changed the functions names. But when I tried to run the new script file. I got errors.  "Invalid argument: id (line 38, file "Code1") Dismiss"

Comment: var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); 
function doGet(e) {
       return addUser4(  e.parameter['userIDG'],e.parameter['userNameG'],
    e.parameter['userAgeG'],e.parameter['userDOBYearG'], 
    e.parameter['userDOBMonthG'], e.parameter['userBornCityG'], 
    e.parameter['userMotherMaidenG'],

Comment: e.parameter['userGrandPaNameG'],
    e.parameter['userElementaryG'],
        e.parameter['userMiddleSchoolG'],
      e.parameter['userEyeColorG'],
      e.parameter['userHairColorG'])
}
function addUser4( userIDG, userNameG,userAgeG,userDOBYearG,userDOBMonthG, userBornCityG, userMotherMaidenG, userGrandPaNameG, userElementaryG, userMiddleSchoolG, userEyeColorG, userHairColorG) {  /// following is line 38, the error code line, it works in ///another project script file
                                                   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));

Comment: @ICanPassDrivingSchoolLLC Please add your code to question.

Comment: @ICanPassDrivingSchoolLLC actually, it looks to me that you should add your code to a new question as it refers to a different issue.

Comment: Thanks. I will do